# Unable to run any query on the table

Tags: sql, hive, bigdata, metastore, hive-metastore

While I am running the following query

```
SELECT * FROM table_unfilter WHERE date='2010-08-01';
```

I am getting

> Failed :error in acquiring locks: Error communicating with the
>   metastore

When I set hive concurrency to false, I am getting

> Failed to use dbtxnmanager set concurrency = true

I am able to query all other tables of same database, but not the above one. 
How can I fix this?

Comment: Is it a transactional table?

Answer (score -1):

Check from AMBARI whether ACID is disabled. IF ACID is disabled, then concurrency should also be set to false.
Then `set hive.support.concurrency=false`
once you run this, make sure to restart the affect components, for the changes to take place.